# unable to do SSO connection for zeppelin

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I am not able to do single sign on for zeppelin also i am not able to configure of R interpreter in zeppelin. As i SAML protocol we can use for SSO but i am not able to find in zeppelin where we have to define SAML tokens so it will be authorized users.

I have installed R in my machine , but while connect R from zeppelin getting "Interpreter doesn't exit " . I followed zeppelin documents for configure R in zeppelin , but getting hard luck.

Can someone please help me on the same.

Answer (score 1):

SSO for Zeppelin can be implemented using Apache Knox. KnoxSSO support is recently added to Zeppelin.

This [document](https://medium.com/data-collective/apache-zeppelin-oauth-integration-using-apache-knox-dea2362e3dda) explains the steps for SSO using OAuth. With few tweaks in Knox configuration SAML based SSO can be done.